# What is the solution set of the system $x^x + y^y = 31$ and $x + y = 5$?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, derivatives, exponential-function, systems-of-equations

It may be easily seen (heuristically) that the only solution (in $\mathbb R$) of the system

$x^x + y^y = 31$ and $ x + y = 5$

is the set containing $ (2, 3)$ and $(3, 2)$.

My question is, how may one go about demonstrating that those are indeed the only intersection points of the two equations? As I said above, I can see why this is so, intuitively, but can't seem to put it down properly.

Thank you.

Comment: Do you mean **integer** solutions?

Comment: Using the second equation, may be we could use the simetry using $x=z+\frac 52$ and $y=z-\frac 52$

Comment: All real solutions, DonAntonio.

Comment: $x^x+(5-x)^{5-x}$ looks convex and differentiating twice seems to confirm it, probably there are easier ways to check.

Comment: Claude Leibovici, I don't see what you mean -- could you explain better? Although I think I've found a way -- see my reply to the answer below -- but I'd like to see other reasons why these are the only solutions. Thank you.

Comment: Countingstuff, I now see what you mean. It seems your answer and Michael's below are essentially the same.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $f(x)=x^x+(5-x)^{5-x}.$

Thus, since $$\left(x^x+(5-x)^{5-x}\right)''=\frac{x^x}{x}+x^x(1+\ln{x})^2+(5-x)^{4-x}+(5-x)^{5-x}(1+\ln(5-x))^2>0,$$
we obtain that $f$ is a convex function, which says yhat

the graph of $f$ and the line $y=31$ have two common points maximum,

which says that our system has two solutions maximum.

But $(3,2)$ and $(2,3)$ they are solutions and we are done!

Comment: Your idea to see the system by using the function f(x) := x^x + (5 - x)^(5 - x) - 31 is useful. With this, one may show that all values of this function in the range 2 < x < 3 are negative and that all values of f for x < 2 and x > 3 are positive. This shows that 2 and 3 are the only points at which f vanishes.

Comment: $f$ is a convex function, which says that the graph of $f$ and the line $y=31$ have two common points maximum. Draw it!

Comment: It seems obvious but how we can prove it ?

Comment: By the definition of the convex function we have:  $f(x)<31$ for all $2<x<3$ and $f(x)>31$ for all $3<x<5$ and for all $0<x<2$.

Comment: It's my reasoning exactly!

Comment: I added something. See now.

Comment: Michael, I now see what you mean. Thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Comment: Indeed, note that in the OP, the first equation is concave while the second is linear. This equally demonstrates the point. Except, of course, it involves messing around with implicit functions and differentials instead.

Comment: I think it's better: $f(x)=x^x+(5-x)^{5-x}$ is a convex function and $g(x)=31$ is a constant.

Comment: Its cleaner to note that $x^x$ is a log-convex function, since $(x \log x)'' = 1/x$, and hence convex. Also the sum of convex functions is convex.

Comment: Yes of course! You are right.

Comment: To see a picture of the region in $\mathbb{R}_+ \times\mathbb{R}_+$ where $x^x+y^y$ exceeds $31$, you can ask [Wolfram Alpha to `plot x^x+y^y>31`](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5Ex%2By%5Ey%3E31).

Comment: I´m not sure if this comment box is the proper way for asking this, but does somebody know if there is an analytical way for finding the solutions $x=2$ and $x=3$? I mean, not by guess or numerical methods...